# Gradient colors not changing if change mode on dark/light when hide app

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, gradient

I have a problem, if I open app in dark/light mode, when hide app, change mode on phone settings when back app again, my gradient not redraws, how can I fix that?

```
final class GradientView: UIView {
    
    var locations: [NSNumber]? = [0.0, 1.0] {
        didSet { updateLocations() }
    }
    
    var colors: [CGColor]? = [Color.backgroundPrimary.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor, Color.backgroundPrimary.cgColor] {
        didSet { updateColors() }
    }
    
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { layer as! CAGradientLayer }
    
    override public class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAGradientLayer.self }
    
    convenience init(_ from: CGColor, _ to: CGColor) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        colors = [from, to]
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateLocations()
        updateColors()
    }
    
    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
                self.updateColors()
            }
        }
    }
}

private extension GradientView {
    
    func updateLocations() {
        gradientLayer.locations = self.locations
    }
    
    func updateColors() {
        gradientLayer.colors = self.colors
    }
}
```

I use my own colors for dark and light mode and it works perfect, but problem with the gradient

```
public static var backgroundPrimary = dynamicColor(light:  colorLiteral(red: 1.00000000000, green: 1.00000000000, blue: 1.00000000000, alpha: 1), dark:  colorLiteral(red: 0.00000000000, green: 0.00000000000, blue: 0.00000000000, alpha: 1))
```

updateColors is calling, but colors not changing

Comment: You need to be more specific when asking for debugging help - what exactly doesn't work? Is `traitCollectionDidChange` not getting called? Is your `updateColors` method not working correctly?

Comment: updateColors is calling, but colors not changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `colors` array is an array of `CGColor`. That does not change based on light/dark trait.

You need to **get** the dynamic color and set the array again:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: previousTraitCollection) {
            self.colors = [UIColor.backgroundPrimary.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor, UIColor.backgroundPrimary.cgColor]
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Alternatively, use an array of `UIColor` (instead of `CGColor`) and you don't need to implement `traitCollectionDidChange`:

```
final class GradientView: UIView {
    
    var locations: [NSNumber]? = [0.0, 1.0] {
        didSet { updateLocations() }
    }
    
    var uiColors: [UIColor] = [UIColor.backgroundPrimary.withAlphaComponent(0), UIColor.backgroundPrimary] {
        didSet { updateColors() }
    }
    
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { layer as! CAGradientLayer }
    
    override public class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAGradientLayer.self }
    
    convenience init(_ from: UIColor, _ to: UIColor) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        uiColors = [from, to]
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateLocations()
        updateColors()
    }
    
}

private extension GradientView {
    func updateLocations() {
        gradientLayer.locations = self.locations
    }
    func updateColors() {
        gradientLayer.colors = self.uiColors.map({$0.cgColor})
    }
}
```